# Implode array with comma separated string but no comma after last string

Tags: php, mysql

I have used `implode` to separate the array. What I want is that my ids should be shown in brackets separated by commas, but after the last string there will be no comma. How can I show them in brackets with no comma after the last string?

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         mysql_connect("localhost", "usename", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
         mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 

         $ids=array();
         $data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM information"); 
         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))  
         {
            $ids[]=$row["id"]; 
         } 
         echo implode(", ", $ids);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think its better to show an example!

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: but using implode, no comma will get add after last string

Comment: Expected output just mention here.

Comment: implode doesn't add a *glue* after the last one array item.

Comment: Nothing wrong with implode, it looks like the last `id` is empty or null. try `var_dump($ids)` see what you got

Comment: `echo '[', implode(", ", $ids), ']';` gives the list in brackets: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` -- is this what you want?`

Comment: Guys, implode in this case does not add brackets around the strings, it will result in `1, 2, 3` instead of `(1), (2), (3)` ... the OP might have tried a loop to add `(`/`)` and failed with the last comma

Comment: numbers work fine,whenever i wanted bring simple string for exapmle names of tv the last string i get is something like this - 
 ' CNN ', 'AMC',
there is a extra comma after the string

Comment: @user3815328 see the answers that Darren and me have provided

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13]; // array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13); for versions below 5.4

$str = "(".implode("), (", $arr).")";

echo $str;
```

Results in

```
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (12), (13)
```

If that's your expected behavior, you just add the opening and closing bracket as delimiters, which will separate the strings by it, but will result in lack of opening and closing bracket  at the beginning and at the end (as it adds the glue AFTER each element, except the last), so you add it manually with concatenation.

It will take `1` and `2` for example and will add after `1` (because `2` is the last, it will only add AFTER `1`) the delimiter `), (` will result in `1), (2`, thus adding the concatenated `(` and `)` results in `(1), (2)`

Answer (score 0):

Provided I followed your question correctly.
You'd use something like this

([*We're passing variables by reference in this example*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)):

```
foreach($ids as $i => &$id) {
    $id = "({$id})";
}

$string = implode(", ", $ids);
```

Which will end up returning something like this:

```
(56), (74), (88), (100), (91), (61), (43), (47), (77), (2), (78), (61), (44), (6), (74), (90), (14), (86), (80)
```

[<kbd>Here is an example</kbd>](https://eval.in/170847) (<sup>*Note: It just uses randomly generated `id`'s*</sup>)

---

In response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903198/implode-array-with-comma-separated-string-but-no-comma-after-last-string/24903280?noredirect=1#comment38688564_24903280):

Even with strings, this function works. [<kbd>**See this example**</kbd>](https://eval.in/170857)

Comment: This will suit the OP needs, but it's an overkill where you are mutating the array for purpose of late presentation, which is also a bad practice according to me. Afterwards each time you try to do something with that array, you will have brackets around each element

Comment: @RoyalBg That is a good point. I wrote this answer assuming the sole purpose of the OP was to create the string that he is `echo`'ing out to the DOM, as seen in his example.

Comment: your code works  in numbers,but whenever i wanted bring simple string for exapmle names of tv the last string i get is something like this - 
 ' CNN ', 'AMC', ''
there is a extra comma plus two apostrophe signs

Comment: @user3815328 Could you supply an example of that set of strings?

Comment: @user3815328 is that not what you wanted?